# Customized Installation path

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, setup-project, installation-path

I am creating a visual studio setup project using vs2010.  I want my application to be installed in `c:\manufacturer\ProductName`.  I used  `[HOMEDRIVE]` as the defaultLocation of "ApplicationFolder" which will points to `c:\` at the installation time. However, when i put `[HOMEDRIVE][Manufacturer]\[ProductName]` as the defaultLocation,  it raises an error at the installation time saying  "Could not access network location  Manufacturer\ProductName".   I appreciate any kind of help or suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this default path:

```
[WindowsVolume][Manufacturer][ProductName]
```

[WindowsVolume](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372817%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property is automatically resolved to the Windows partition (usually C:). Also, all predefined folder property values are ended with a backslash (). So you don't need to add one after WindowsVolume.

Comment: @ Cosmin Prirvu : thanks for the reply, It seems it is necessary to put that backslash else the path would be appear like  c:\ Manufacturer ProductName\